# I apply addevent listener on multiple items and also make the content editable, but it didn't worked?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener, contenteditable

I am trying to make the note title editable when someone clicks on it.
It worked when applied on a single note but its (contenteditable) function is not working on all elements.
Here is the javascript code:

```
let notecardTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("cardtitle");
for(let i = 0 ; i < notecardTitle.length ; i++){
notecardTitle[i].addEventListener("click", function changeTitle(e) {
        console.log("change", e);
        notecardTitle.contentEditable = 'true';    
    });
}
```

I am applying this event-listener on this note which is also made in javascript

```
let showBox = "";
    noteData.forEach(function(element, index) {
        showBox += `<div class="noteCard my-2 mx-2 card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="cardtitle">Note 
                  ${index + 1}
                  </h5>
                  <p class="card-text"> 
                  ${element}
                  </p>
                  <button id="${index}" onclick="deleteNote(this.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Note</a>
                </div>
              </div>   `
            })
```

Leave the NoteData line. This is the code on which i am applying event-listener `<h5 class="cardtitle">Note`

Thanks

Comment: May you provide a html code as well? You may use [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/14032355) to make a working example as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: `notecardTitle.contentEditable` should be `notecardTitle[i].contentEditable`

Comment: Why don't you just use the `contenteditable=true` attribute in the HTML? That automatically allows you to click on it to edit it.

Comment: @Barmar Yes i can also add it in HTML but as i am learning and while learning building this project. I am trying different things.
One issue i am facing is that
When the someone adds a note and then click on the title, the code up in the post doesn't work. It works great until someone has added a new note.
Should i share the whole code?
I would really appreciate if anyone can guide

Comment: Issue resolved
I just made the whole code a function and ran it at the start of the code (at the top) and it worked.